# I want to create a compiler in android for C language like C4droid app

Tags: android

I want to create a compiler in android for C language like C4droid app.
In my app i can write c language code and i can compile the code and run it.

If anyone can help me to made this project in android. i will be very thankfull of that person..

How it is possible,please help me.

Comment: Help Center: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the related [don't-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an official C/C++ toolset for Android: [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

> The NDK is a toolset that allows you to implement parts of your app
>   using native-code languages such as C and C++.